# Middle-ware function not working in node.js

Tags: node.js, jwt, middleware

I am beginner to JS. I am trying to build authentication with jwt token.

I have 3 users in the system (role: admin, doctor & patient). I am passing user id & user role in the payload to generate token. I am passing these as String.

I have one middleware for authentication which is auth.js

I am trying to write another which would limit route's (routes/api/admin/me) access only to admin. the same is in adminguard.js. (I am trying to extract the role and check condition)

Request help with the second middleware function or kindly suggest better solution.

routes/api/systemusers.js - (Route file)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {check,validationResult}=require('express-validator/check');
const SystemUser = require('../../models/SystemUser')
const bcrypt=require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config =require('config');

// @ route  POST api/systemuser
// @ desc   Register user
// @ access Public
router.post('/',[
    check('username','please enter username').not().isEmpty(),
    check('role','please enter role').not().isEmpty(),
    check('password','please enter 6 or more characters').isLength({min:6}).not()
],
async (req,res)=>{
    const errors=validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array()});
    }
    const {username, role, password }=req.body;
    try {
        //check for duplicate username request
        let user = await SystemUser.findOne({ username });

        if (user) {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'User already exists' }] });
        }
        systemuser = new SystemUser({
            username,
            role,
            password
          });
          //bcrypt pass word
          const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

          systemuser.password=await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

          await systemuser.save();

          //return Jsonwebtoken
          const payload = {
            systemuser: {
              id: systemuser.id,
              role:systemuser.role
            }
          };

          jwt.sign(
            payload,
            config.get('jwtSecret'),
             (err, token) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              res.json({ token });
            }
          );
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }

    });

module.exports=router;
```

auth.js (middleware)

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  // Get token from header
  const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

  // Check if not token
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, authorization denied' });
  }

  // Verify token
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));

    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Token is not valid' });
  }
};
```

adminguard.js (middleware)

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    if(req.user && req.user.role !='admin') {
      next(new Error('You are not an admin'));
    } else {
      console.log();
      next();
    }
}
```

server.js (main file)

```
const express =require("express");
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app=express();

//connect databse
connectDB();

//init middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>res.send('API running'));

//Define routes

app.use('/api/systemusers',require('./routes/api/systemusers'));
app.use('/api/auth',require('./routes/api/auth'));
app.use('/api/admin',require('./routes/api/admin'));


const PORT =process.env.PORT|5000;

app.listen(PORT, ()=>console.log(`Server started on PORT ${PORT}`));
```

models/SystemUser

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const SystemUserSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    role:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
});

module.exports=SystemUser=mongoose.model('systemuser',SystemUserSchema);
```

Comment: The more important change is to deny every non user. This: `req.user && req.user.role !='admin'` allows everone who is not a user at all

Comment: @bambam : Thank you for your help. Could please explain in detail not sure I follow what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest returning an HTTP 403 if the user is not an admin rather than using `next`:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    if(!req.user || req.user.role !='admin') {
      res.status(403).send('You are not an admin');
      return;
    } else {
      console.log('User is an admin');
      next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for help. I tried the solution suggested, I am getting an "You are not admin" error for user with role admin.. Kindly help.

Comment: Can you add `console.log(req.user)` above the `if` statement and see what it says?  Maybe `admin` is capitalized?

Comment: Can you please add `console.log(decoded)` above the line `req.user = decoded.user;` in `auth.js`?

Comment: Hi Matt, below is the result:{ systemuser: { id: '5d015bbb37854754f485d559', role: 'admin' },
  iat: 1560370107,
  exp: 1560730107 }
undefined

Comment: Ok, so you need to reference it via `decoded.systemuser` rather than `decoded.user` in `auth.js`.  The code should be: `req.user = decoded.systemuser;` (because `user` is not defined anywhere in the `decoded` variable)